# remove the class after closing fancybox 4

Tags: javascript, fancybox

in version 3 it was like this:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    afterClose: function () {
        //window.location.reload();
        $(".modal-content").removeClass("active");
    },
});
```

How to write the same in version 4?

Comment: Here you can find all events and usage samples for Fancybox 4 - https://web.archive.org/web/20230108195740/https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox]', {
 on: {
  destroy: function (fancybox, event) {
   document.querySelectorAll('.modal-content').forEach(function (content) {
    content.classList.remove('active');
   });
  },
 },
});
```